# Reactive search filter available filters

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I have set up a sample application based on filtering car sales

https://codesandbox.io/s/h0eb4

I've set up simple 'Make' and 'Model' filters, but I want the 'Model' filter to update based on the 'Make' field.

Do I need to dig into elastic search API to do this with custom aggregations, or is there a way of doing this using the reactive search UI components?

If someone can either advise me on the pure elastic search way of doing this, (post parameters for the queries) or using the reactive search UI components, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to add a `react` property to the Model list, which causes it to respond to changes in the Make list (`list-1` in your sandbox).

```
react={{and:"list-1"}}
```

Here is a fork of your sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dew-4zhep